# How to open Modal from another component in react-native

Tags: react-native

I have tried to open Modal from another component in react-native, but modal is not open. so please help me if have any solution. this is my code

```
modal.js

import React from './node_modules/react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

const ProfileModal = () => {
    return (
            <View>
                <Text>HELLO TEXT</Text>
            </View>
    );
}

export default ProfileModal;

----------------------------------------
header.js
import ProfileModal from './ProfileModal';
import { Image, View, TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';
import Modal from 'react-native-modal';

const openLoginPopup = () => {
 return (
           <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.openModal}>
            <Text> Login </Text>
           </TouchableOpacity>
        )
}

const openModal = () => {
  return (
    <Modal isVisible={true}>
       <ProfileModal />
    </Modal>
  )

}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Please post some code with your question which shows what you have tried so far.

Comment: you can use redux!

Comment: Thanks @DmitriBorohhov, 
i have added my code in post please check

Answer (score 5):

In that case, react-native-modal provide callback onBackdropPress, onBackButtonPress to close.

You can use it like this:

```
const ProfileModal = ({ open, onClose }) => {
  return (
    <Modal isVisible={open} onBackButtonPress={onClose} onBackdropPress={onClose}>
      <View>
        <Text>HELLO TEXT</Text>{' '}
      </View>
    </Modal>
  )
}
```

Then pass onClose function when using it:

```
 <ProfileModal open={open} onClose={()=> setOpen(false)} />
```

Comment: Thanks it is what i was looking for @phoMai

Answer (score 1):

It's like you write the content modal in modal file. So you can do it something like:

```
modal.js

import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

const ProfileModal = () => {
    return (
            <View>
                <Text>HELLO TEXT</Text>
            </View>
    );
}

export default ProfileModal;

----------------------------------------
header.js
import ProfileModal from './ProfileModal';
import { Image, View, TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';
import Modal from 'react-native-modal';

const Header = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)
  return (
    <View>
      {/* some content */}

      {/* btn trigger */}

       <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setOpen(true)}>
          <Text> Login </Text>
       </TouchableOpacity>


      <Modal isVisible={open}>
        <ProfileModal />
      </Modal>
    </View>
  )
}
```

or

```
modal.js

import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

const ProfileModal = ({ open }) => {
    return (
      <Modal isVisible={open}>
        <View>
           <Text>HELLO TEXT</Text>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    );
}

export default ProfileModal;

----------------------------------------
header.js
import ProfileModal from './ProfileModal';
import { Image, View, TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';
import Modal from 'react-native-modal';

const Header = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)
  return (
    <View>
      {/* some content */}

      {/* btn trigger */}

       <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setOpen(true)}>
          <Text> Login </Text>
       </TouchableOpacity>


        <ProfileModal open={open} />
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: How to close it @pho mai, it is not closing by click on button ?

Comment: The modal open by the "open" props. So if you want to toggle by 1 btn, you could change  onPress={() => setOpen(true)} to  onPress={() => setOpen(!open)}

Comment: No, i don't want toggle, but i want to close on onBackdropPress event.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `openModal` method is not part of `openLoginPopup` so remove this before `openModal` method.

Just use directly like below,

```
const openLoginPopup = () => {
 return (
           <TouchableOpacity onPress={openModal}>
            <Text> Login </Text>
           </TouchableOpacity>
        )
}
```

Second issue was that you also don't need arrow function in onPress event until you want to pass some parameters in openModal method. You can directly pass the method name and it will work.